# How to find probability without replacement using only pandas and random?

Tags: python, pandas, random

The simulation has square as both shape1 and shape2 but it shouldn't happen if we run without replacement. I know the code runs well but I don't know how to solve this situation.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
```

creating the simulation

```
def simulation1():
    shape1 = random.choice(["square", "pentagon", "octagon"])
    return shape1
def simulation2():
    shape2 = random.choice(["square", "pentagon", "octagon"])
    return shape2
```

storing the simulation as a dataframe

```
data = []
for i in range(1000):
    d = {"shape1": simulation1(), "shape2": simulation2()}
    data.append(d)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: you need to use words to describe the problem you are having in the post

Comment: dont just post a picture of the problem, it's like you are asking us to do your homework. what's the specific issue?

Comment: My bad first ever post, I don't know what I am missing to run the simulation to draw these objects without replacement. So when viewing the dataframe it shouldn't have an observation repeated twice. However I wanted to see if it was possible without importing numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. You just need to modify the list after the first selection is done. Of course there are many other ways to implement this.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

def simulation(choices):
    shape = random.choice(choices)
    return shape

data = []
for i in range(1000):
    d = {}
    x = ["square", "pentagon", "octagon"] 
    d['shape1'] = simulation (x) #item 1 is selected
    x.remove(d['shape1']) #item selected previously is removed from the list
    d['shape2'] = simulation (x) #item 2 is selected without item 1 in the list
    data.append(d) #items in list are reset in the next loop
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The df looks like this,

```
    shape1  shape2
0   octagon     pentagon
1   pentagon    octagon
2   pentagon    octagon
3   octagon     square
4   square  octagon
...     ...     ...
995     octagon     square
996     octagon     pentagon
997     pentagon    octagon
998     square  octagon
999     square  pentagon
```

You can test if there are any duplicates by doing this,

```
df['duplicates'] = np.where(df.shape1 == df.shape2, 1, 0) #return a 1 if there are duplicates
df.duplicates.sum() #sum the 3rd column
```

If the sum is greater than 0, means there are duplicates. I got 0 therefore no duplicates.

You don't even have to define a function, you can do this instead and get the same result.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

data = []
for i in range(1000):
    d = {}
    x = ["square", "pentagon", "octagon"] 
    d['shape1'] = random.choice(x) #item 1 is selected
    x.remove(d['shape1']) #item selected previously is removed from the list
    d['shape2'] = random.choice(x) #item 2 is selected without item 1 in the list
    data.append(d) #items in list are reset in the next loop
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Finally you can use a function that was built for random sampling without replacement.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

data = []
x = ["square", "pentagon", "octagon"]
for i in 1000:
    shapes = random.sample(x, k=2) #k=2 means you want to pick 2 items without replacement. a list of items containing 2 shapes is created
    data.append({"shape1": shapes[0], "shape2": shapes[1]})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this is not a good question but why did you only define shape1 in the simulation(choices) instead of both

Comment: @Sukwha okay so that name doesnt matter. its just a variable within the function, take a look again i changed it to a more general name.

Comment: ok that makes sense, and just to ask when you are doing the "d['shape2'] = simulation(x)" how does it know to select an w/o item 1 in list

Comment: Because I removed the item that was picked in shape1 using the command in the line before

Answer (score 1):

`Random.sample()` is more appropriate here than `random.choice()`.

```
sample(population, k, *, counts=None) method of random.Random instance
    Chooses k unique random elements from a population sequence or set.

    Returns a new list containing elements from the population while
    leaving the original population unchanged.
    ...
```

```py
import random
import pandas as pd

x = ["square", "pentagon", "octagon"]
d = []
for _ in 1000:
    shapes = random.sample(x, k=2)
    d.append({"shape1": shapes[0], "shape2": shapes[1]})

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```